# Insert media while posting is not working with new wordpress update

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

Insert media while editing or adding post is not working since the 4.1.2 update. But I can upload media through media manager itself.

I didn't change anything in the site today, only the automatic update to wordpress 4.1.2. But since then I found this issue.

And the funny thing is I have two instance of same wordpress site and both of them updated in the morning. But one is working as normal, but one is not working.

When I debug it with console I saw that the working instance is using `POST asynce-upload.php` while other one using `POST admin-ajax.php` to upload media.

Anyone has an idea about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the `post thumbnail editor` plugin, then everything started to work again as normal.

But for the general advise for similar kind of issue is, disable your plugins one by one and test. Then you can find the plugin which is not compatible with wordpress update. So that you can disable that plugin at lease until it is giving new update.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-412-update-image-upload-not-working